# xsl: passing variable into xsl file path

Tags: xslt

Is there a way pass a attribute, variable combinations directly into the path of the url with xsl?

Example:

```
http://something.xsl?asdf=12&attribute2=1234
```

I would like to use these attributes and values to enable certain flags inside the xsl file.

Answer (score 0):

Use `concat()`

```
<xsl:variable name="url" select="concat($currURL, 'flag=true')" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you just need to escape the `&` as `&amp;`

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean can the stylesheet access its own URI to access the parameters. In XSLT2 you can use the static-base-uri() function to access the URI, and then you can split it up to extract the query parameters using the regex string functions.  In XSLT1 it is not possible, you would need to pass the information in as stylesheet parameters, and XSLT1 stylesheet has no access to the URI of the source or itself.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a complete XSLT 1.0 solution, assuming that the URL is passed as an external parameter to the transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="ext">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:param name="pUrl" select=
 "'http://something.xsl?asdf=12&amp;attribute2=1234'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="vQuery" select="substring-after($pUrl, '?')"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vrtfQueryItems">
   <xsl:call-template name="buildQueryItems">
     <xsl:with-param name="pQuery" select="$vQuery"/>
   </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="vQueryItems"
    select="ext:node-set($vrtfQueryItems)/*"/>

  <xsl:copy-of select="$vQueryItems"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="buildQueryItems">
   <xsl:param name="pQuery"/>

   <xsl:if test=
    "string-length($pQuery) > 0">

   <xsl:variable name="vQuery" select="concat($pQuery, '&amp;')"/>
   <xsl:variable name="vItem" select="substring-before($vQuery, '&amp;')"/>

   <param name="{substring-before(concat($vItem, '='), '=' )}">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($vItem, '=')"/>
   </param>


   <xsl:call-template name="buildQueryItems">
    <xsl:with-param name="pQuery" select="substring-after($pQuery, '&amp;')"/>
   </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on any XML document (not used), the wanted result is produced**:

```
<param name="asdf">12</param>
<param name="attribute2">1234</param>
```